# После десериализации в методе объекта, при запуске новго Thread не вызывается handler.post()

Tags: android, gson, десериализация, android-handler

использую Gson от гугла.

после десериализации, не отрабатывает **handler.post()**, помогите разобраться,
вот код метода из десереализованного класса:

```
class Class0 (){
        void damageItem() {
                this.busy = true;
                item_for_runnable = this;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                Thread damagItemThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(getRandom(250, 500));
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "before");
                            handler.post(damage);
                            Log.d(TAG, "after");
                            if (helth < 1) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        item_for_runnable.busy = false;
                    }

                });
                damagItemThread.start();
            }
          Runnable damage = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "in runnabe");
                ...
            }
        };
    }
```

**damagItemThread** запускается, но **handler.post()** просто пробегает, не запуская **damage**. Если объект "новый", а не десериализованный, то все работает как задумано. Не пойму в чем проблема :(

вывод в лог из новго объекта:

```
07-17 17:54:57.749 27053-27480/ D/my: before
07-17 17:54:57.749 27053-27480/ D/my: after
07-17 17:54:57.749 27053-27053/ D/my: in runnabe
```

вывод от десериализованного:

```
07-17 17:56:09.659 27053-27504/D/my: before
07-17 17:56:09.659 27053-27504/D/my: after
```

Comment: непонятно откуда взялся damage, какой у него тип и т.д. как вы его обрабатываете в looper (tесли он не Runnable)?

Comment: я просто расписывать не стал. обычный Runnable для выполнения кода в UI, сейчас дополню

Comment: хмм, видимо от того, что Runnable находится в этом классе, он не передается на выполнение в UI после десериализации

Comment: Что значит _пробегает_ - `post()` ставит Ваш `Runnable` в очередь и всё.  
Потом, когда очередь дойдёт `Runnable` выполнится - поставьте вывод лога в `run()` и убедитесь.

Comment: добавил вывод логов, логи подтверждают, что  Runnable не выполняется :(

Comment: в режиме отладки, если выполнить handler.post(damag) в режиме step in to, 
 в post передается null почему-то :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился переносом инициализации Runnable в конструктор по-умолчанию, который вызывается при десериализации и инициализирует Runnable

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся)

Comment: При использовании JSON сериализации, отделяйте код от данных и не будет подобных проблем в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо учту, опыта нет )